# compare values in column C if column B exists

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have 2 excel files (separated in time) with several columns; One of the columns is a client name and the other a value;
I need to compare the values between the columns if they exist in both and if not just represent it, for example:

```
01/01/2020                   01/02/2020         
file 1:                      file 2:               Expected result
NAME   VALUE                  NAME   VALUE          NAME   VALUE
AA       1                    AA     7              AA     6
BB       10                   BB     5              BB     -5
CC       10                   DD     8              CC     -10
                                                    DD     8
```

Is this possible only using basic excel functionality or do I requiere a MACRO (VBA)?

Comment: `VLOOKUP` `MATCH` `INDEX` WHat have you tried?

Comment: Shouldn't the result of CC be `-10` ? • And yes you would need VBA unless the result list of names already exists.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ You're correct! Thanks, I'll edit right away.

Comment: So does the list of names that is shown in "Expected result" already exist? Then it can be done with formulas only.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ It should be the combination of all the values of both columns (AA is in both files, but CC is only in file 1 and DD only in file 2) There isn't a table with all the names anywhere.

Comment: Well, then you need VBA to create that unique list and  eg use VLookup to get the values und subtract them. Give it a try yourself and if you get stuck or errors come back with your code and a question related to that code.

Comment: Alternativeley you can copy both name lists to the result sheet manually and use the remove duplicates feature of Excel. And then use a `=VLOOKUP` formula to get and subtract the values for these unique names.

Comment: Have you tried to search "reconciliation with Pivot Table"? It is the easiest way to compare two tables with a common field like in your case Name

Comment: @Pᴇʜ is this pivot the solution? or am I missing something? How could you get CC be -10?

Comment: @NareshBhople He does not sum. He does a subtraction: `result = file 2 - file 1`. • CC is `-10` because CC in `file 2` is missing means CC is `0` and `0-10 = -10`. So your pivot is probably not the solution.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ ..Got it but can be easily calculated with this pivot? ..Thanks

Comment: @NareshBhople Maybe but since he needs to create a intermediate table for that pivot (either by VBA or manually) he can use remove duplicates and `VLOOKUP` as well, see no benefit in the pivot then.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ .. True. Especially if data is huge, it may not be feasible to create a new such table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To support my comment above here is a pivot table reconciliation solution. Create a third table as shown and the pivot. For the resulting columns next to Pivot, "Generate GetPivotData" is turned off for easy reference to pivot cells.

[image]